# Searching for recomended UI architecture source

Tags: architecture, user-interface

I get too often faced with UI architecture dilemmas.
For example:

- Do I have to show message box in that point ?
- where should I locate the refresh button

.. etc.

Is there a recommended book,blog, article about it ?

Comment: this question should probably go on [UX stackexchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'd throw this over to UX.SE but in it's current form it's just a bit too vague and open ended. If you smartened up the question by providing examples of what you've tried in the past and why you think they're not working well then you'd probably have a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really asking about architecture, it seems, but about UI design. The best book I know on this subject is Alan Cooper's [About Face 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764526413), which is very readable and also thought-provoking.